# Specific dimens.xml(hYYYdp) file is not working as expected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen-support

I have the following dimens file:

[image]

I have tested the app in a 240x**400**px (ldpi) device. So the height's dp is = **400**/(120(ldpi)/160)== 533.33dp

So if I am not wrong, dimens.xml(h533dp) will be used by devices whose height's dp is equal or grater to 533dp. So, why if I am testing the app in a device with 533.33dp of height, it is not using the dimens that are defined in dimens.xml(h533dp)? I'm going off my head...

Comment: 533 < 533.33  Turn it into h530dp and see if that fixes it.  The real question is WHY are you doing this to begin with-  anytime you make a layout file this specific, it means you have a major programming mistake in your UI and you're trying to bandaid it.  That's always a mistake- you'll need to make so many of these and spend so much time, effort, and bugs maintaining them that it's never correct to do this rather than fix the real problem.

Comment: @GabeSechan The purpose of having different values according to the screen size is because I have a ConstraintLayout with some items that have Top and Bottom margin and in some devices that margin is not looking good. In this post I made, someone suggested me to use different margin values according to the screen size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74675738/how-to-solve-textview-being-cropped-in-small-devices-because-of-layout-margin .

Comment: After that post, I made another that didn't have any answer. I made it to ask how many different dimens.xml files I had to create to support all the devices as there are a big amount of different devices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756490/how-many-dimens-files-are-needed-to-support-all-the-devices-according-to-the-scr . For what you are telling me, I think it is not a good solution to create different dimens files to fix the problem. I would appreciate a lot if you could lend me a helping hand :)

Comment: You can use different margins for different screen size, but it wouldn't be a *specific* screen size.  It would be wide categories of screen size.  Most apps have 2-3 of these at most, across everything from the smallest device to the biggest tablet.

Comment: @GabeSechan --It would be wide categories of screen size-- that's the point, I would like to know how could I know all the dimens.xml(hYYYdp) files I have to create so that all the screen sizes are managed. --Most apps have 2-3 of these at most-- what I have done is to make a dimens file that is working for a speific device (240x400px (ldpi)) and my plan is to make more and more of different devices like this one. But, now I am confused because you have told me that dimens files should't be created for specific screen size devices and most apps only have 2-3 spcecific devices dimens files

Comment: If I don't have to create specific dimens files to manage/support all the screen size devices, what should I do? Please I would like you to help me as I have seen that I am not doing it correctly and there is a better way to do it. Please, you can answer me here or in the question of dimens files I made. You don't know how much I would appreciate it because I am already a bit desperate with this topic because I can't find so much information on what dimens.xml files I should create exactly and how many of them. Thanks :)

Comment: @GabeSechan sorry for too much questions, but why 530 is working and 533 isn't if 533 < 533.33 but also 530 <533.3 ? What is the difference between 533 and 530?